# Is there an Unique Generating Set of a Group when Cardinality of the set is fixed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$A$ is a generating set of permutation-group $G$ (not a p-group), i.e. $\langle A \rangle=G$. $|A| \leq \log_2(|G|)$.

$A$ has possible maximum  number of elements to generate $G$.

It means that the next possible generating set of $G$, say $C$, has cardinality $> \log(|G|)$. There is no generating set between $A$ and $C$.

Is there another set $B$ with the same cardinality of $A$ and  $\langle B \rangle =G$ ?

---

**Edit:**

1. Note that every subgroup of $ Sym(n)$ (symmetric group) can be generated by at most $n$ elements
   , this bound has been lowered, using the classification, to $[ n /2 ]$
   if $n > 3$ (P. Neumann).

Comment: For the edit what do you mean? so you don't want the maximal number of elements? And do you want non-generators with respect to this size restriction?

Comment: So there could be a generator that seems like a non generator for small sets, but maybe there is some larger set where it is a generator. So if you only consider generating sets of a certain size it might look like some element is a non generator but when you consider your definition it isn't a non generator.

Comment: @PaulPlummer , if i say , a minimal  generating set of  maximum size, does it clear things up? For example, $A, B$ have no non generator and their size is same, $C$ is another gen:  set $|C|>A$ but $C$ has non generator. There is no generating set between the size of $A$ and $C$.